# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object with intervention Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filesystem

I'm having issues writing a function. When I try to update the file image, I get the error in `getClientOriginalName().`

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array

```php
<?php

/**
 * Upload File.
 *
 * @param array $input
 * @return array $input
 */
public function uploadImg($input)
{
    if (isset($input['featured_image']) && !empty($input['featured_image'])) {
        $avatar = $input['featured_image'];
        $fileName = time() . $avatar->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->storage->put($this->upload_path . $fileName, file_get_contents($avatar->getRealPath()));
        $path = 'posts_images/' . $fileName;
        $input = array_merge($input, ['featured_image' => $path]);
    } elseif (isset($input['img']) && !empty($input['img'])) {
        $avatar = $input['img'];
        $fileName = time() . $avatar->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->storage->put($this->upload_path . $fileName, file_get_contents($avatar->getRealPath()));
        $path = 'posts_images/' . $fileName;
        $input = array_merge($input, ['img' => $path]);
    }

    return $input;
}
```

Comment: `$avatar` variable is an array so that you have to iterate over it before using `getClientOriginalName()` function

Answer (score 2):

Try below lines

```
public function uploadImg(Request $request){

  $request->file('featured_image')->getClientOriginalName();
}
```

or

```
$file = Input::file('featured_image');
$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
$file->getClientOriginalName();
```

or

```
Input::file('featured_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

---

Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads) of the documentation.